# SQL insert into SELECT from function returns same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have the following function which returns new code based on Month of @Date

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NewCode](@Date date)
    RETURNS nvarchar(4) AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @LastCode nvarchar(4);
    SET @LastCode = (SELECT MAX(Code) FROM TABLE1 WHERE MONTH(TDate) = MONTH(@Date))
    IF @LastCode IS NULL
        SET @LastCode = '0001';
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @LastCode = CONVERT(nvarchar,(CONVERT(int, @LastCode) + 1));
            WHILE LEN(@LastCode) < 4
                BEGIN
                    SET @LastCode = '0' + @LastCode;
                END
        END

            RETURN @LastCode;
    END
```

then when I insert new data using the above function, I get the same value for each row.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT T1, T2, T3, dbo.NewCode(Table2.TDate) FROM Table2
```

How can I make this function evaluates per row not per query ?

Thank you.

Comment: `dbo.NewCode()` is a scalar function so it would be execute per row.

Comment: Couple of things to possibly check. First, select all the CODE values from Table1 and ensure all of them are 4 characters long. Values of '0034', '1000', '33' would select 33 as the MAX. If the data is ok, check the collation. If you can, store numbers as numbers to overcome possibly gotchas like the above "sorting"

Comment: I suspect the issue you're having is that you want each inserted row to be included in the calculations being done by the function. So if a row gets inserted with the new code 34, then you want the next row in the same month to have code 35, but it is also being set to 34. You could use some kind of `ROW_NUMBER()` function and add its value to the number in your `NewCode` function.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Just use an `IDENTITY` and convert that to your fancy identifier afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly an answer to your question and I don't know if this is the best possible approach, but I think it may solve your problem. Just generate value for each selected row (using `ROW_NUMBER()`) and add this value to the result of your function. The function is changed and returns integer value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NewCode] (
    @Date date
)
RETURNS numeric(4, 0) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LastCode numeric(4, 0);
    SET @LastCode = (SELECT MAX(Code) FROM TABLE1 WHERE MONTH(TDate) = MONTH(@Date))
    IF @LastCode IS NULL 
        SET @LastCode = 1;
    ELSE
        SET @LastCode = CONVERT(int, @LastCode) + 1;
    RETURN @LastCode;
END

INSERT INTO Table1 
SELECT 
    T1, T2, T3, 
    RIGHT('0000' + CAST(dbo.NewCode(Table2.TDate) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T1) - 1 AS varchar(4)), 4)
    FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

since you'r using `Table2's Date` column for inserting data in Table1, Simply check there should be date value for different months in Table2. your function will work perfect for each row.